# Find all functions $g$ such that $\nabla^2g = x^3+y^2+z$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, laplacian

> Find all functions $g$ such that $$\nabla^2g = x^3+y^2+z$$

---

What I tried:

Basically $\nabla^2$ gradient of a divergence and we can write it as

$$\nabla^2 g = \frac{\partial^2g}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2g}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial z^2} = x^3+y^2+z$$

How do I solve it? Help me, please.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Not everyone is supposed to be fluent in English, don't be rude :) Stay safe and healthy.

Comment: I would recommend some guessing. Note that you have a sum of things with just one variable in each

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, note that with

$g(x, y, z) = \dfrac{1}{20}x^5 + \dfrac{1}{12}y^4 + \dfrac{1}{6}z^3, \tag 1$

we have

$\nabla^2 g = \dfrac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2} + \dfrac{\partial^2 g}{\partial y^2} + \dfrac{\partial^2 g}{\partial z^2} = x^3 + y^2 + z; \tag 2$

now suppose $f(x, y, z)$ also satisfies (2), that is

$\nabla^2 f = x^3 + y^2 + z; \tag 3$

then subtracting (3) from (2) we find

$\nabla^2(g - f) = 0,\tag 4$

that is, $g - f$ is a harmonic function; likewise, with $g - f$ harmonic we have

$\nabla^2 (g - (g - f)) = \nabla^2 g - \nabla^2(g - f) = \nabla^2 g = x^3 + y^2 + z; \tag 5$

it follows that the set of all functions on $\Bbb R^3$ satisfying (2) are precisely those differing from $g(x, y, z)$ by a function harmonic on all of $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: Well, don't quit now!! What are the functions harmonic on all of $\Bbb R^3$? :)